# How can I access the entity tree created by QSceneLoader?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I am trying to access the geometry and material of a mesh loaded with QSceneLoader, but I dont know how.

The [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qsceneloader.html) says

> Given a 3D source file, the Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader will try to parse it and build a tree of Qt3DCore::QEntity objects with proper Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer, Qt3DCore::QTransform and Qt3DRender::QMaterial components.

but it doesnt say how to access that tree. The .component() function seems to be a solution, but it needs an entity name wich I dont have.

I found a file with tests for QSceneLoader using the .component() function (here)[https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt3d/tests/auto/render/qsceneloader/tst_qsceneloader.cpp.html ], but they seem to build the entity tree manually or something.

I could use the Qmesh Class, but QSceneLoader supports far more file formats including fbx and glTF, wich I want to support.

If this is not possible, an alternative is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a working solution in this post:

[Qt3d Using QSceneLoader with qt 5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974307/qt3d-using-qsceneloader-with-qt-5-8)

The SceneWalker does exactly what i need.